# Arithmetic operations in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

It's my first time using PyCharm and when I try to do arithmetic operations and run the program, I don't see any output in console. When I print my operation's result, however, I see it.

```
20/2 
no result

print(20/2)
10.0
```

Why is that? Thank You.

Comment: Running a script does not work the same way as typing in the Python shell. It does not print output of expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write statements in a file and execute them, to see an output you should use statements like `print()`.

To have an interactive session, use `Python Console` in Pycharm. It gives a REPL interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Tools > Python Console` in PyCharm to get a console window

[image]

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 57221 57222
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> 20/2
10.0
```